# How to now get data from OData feed using Reactive Extensions without IEvent?

Tags: system.reactive

Seems the Reactive Extensions team at Microsoft removed the IEvent interface from the library and so now the following code that worked until recently does not compile:

```
using ODataServiceReference;
public static IObservable<IEvent<LoadCompletedEventArgs>> GetInvoices(Uri uri)
{
    var context = new ODataEntities(uri);
    var invoices = new DataServiceCollection<ODataEntities.Invoice>(context);

    var observable = Observable.FromEvent<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(
                                i => invoices.LoadCompleted += i,
                                 i => invoices.LoadCompleted -= i);

    var query = from i in context.Invoices
        select i;

    invoices.LoadAsync(query);
    return observable;
}
```

I am trying to discover the best way to get the result of a query from a WCF Data Services DataServiceCollection object. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `Observable.FromEvent` to `Observable.FromEventPattern` and you should be compiling again.

You *may* want to consider selecting just the good bits however:

```
var eventxs = Observable.FromEvent<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(
                                i => invoices.LoadCompleted += i,
                                 i => invoices.LoadCompleted -= i);
var observable = eventxs.Select(ep => ep.EventArgs.Data);
```